# Why is $I\subset J$ necessary for defining the quotient $J/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $J$ be a proper ideal of a Ring $R$.Then $J/I$ is a proper ideal of $R/I$ if $I$ is contained in $J$ and $I$ is an ideal of $J$. My question is why the condition "$I$ is contained in $J$" necessary?

Comment: If not, then how would you define $J/I$?

Comment: What does '$I$ is an ideal of $J$' mean if $I \not\subseteq J$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: And how about the problems you'll face if $\hat x \in J/I$ then $\hat x=\hat 0$ iff $x \in I$ ?

Comment: Also from wikipidia, "In a quotient of a group, the equivalence class of the identity element is always a normal subgroup of the original group, and the other equivalence classes are precisely the cosets of that normal subgroup." And it is very similar in the case of rings so check the definition of a quotient ring and how it is constructed and you'll understand I think

Comment: Take 5Z/6Z, 6Z is the zero element for 5Z/6Z so it is turning out to be a Ring.Am i making any mistake?